# how can i change the type of storing Dict from row to column using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a simple question. I am using this code to store dictionary of dictionaries in csv file.

```
data = dataA,dataB, dataC, dataD
w = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w"))
for x in data:
    for field, possible_values in x.items():
        print(field, possible_values)
        w.writerow([field, possible_values])
```

The stored values which I got in csv are stored in rows but I want them to be stored as column.

My actual result in csv:

```
name: Alex
Old: 22
```

My target in csv is should be like this:

```
Name  Old
Alex  22
```

How can I change it?

Update1:

the clue is `for key in x.keys()`. After many hours of hard work i updated my code like that and it works better than before but i still have a small issue to get a new line at the end of storing all values and keys x.keys() and y.values(). of my dictioanries in csv file

```
 if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    outfile = open(filename, "w")
    #outfile.write("#Sequence,,,,") 
    for x in data:
        print(x.keys())
        for key in x.keys():
            print(key)
            store_key= key + ","
            outfile = open(filename, "a")
            outfile.write(store_key)
            outfile.close()


    for y in data:
        print(y.values())
        for value in y.values():
            print(value)
            store_value = value + ","    
            outfile = open(filename, "a")
            outfile.write(store_value)
            outfile.close
```

Now i need to seperate maybe with "\n" between keys and values to get the the values od arays under the line of keys.

Any help yill be appreciated.

Comment: post the expected output for multiple dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to access and write to file, this will slow down your code. Hold the output text in a string, delete last comma(,) and add a newline character to end of the string. It will speed up your code, and new line will be added. You can do same for the *second for loop* too.

```
line = ""
for x in data:
    for key in x.keys():
        line += key + ","

line = line[:-1]+"\n" # Delete last character and add new line 
outfile = open(filename, "a")
outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: i can't use the function because i need to store  list of disionaries in csv file yithout [ ] and ' "
for x in data:
    outfile = open(filename, "a")
    outfile.write(str(x.keys()))
    outfile.close()
the problem which i have now that i got in csv file all the symbols of dictionary because iam using str(). 
When i dont use str() i got an error that yrite argument must be a str not dic_keys

Comment: @AhmyOhlin Can you add your expected result to your question for `data = [{"name": "Alex", "age": "22", "sex": "male"}, {"name": "Alice", "age": "19", "sex": "female"}]`

Comment: If you stick with your first code and use `w.writerow(x.keys())` like @Dustin said, you don't have to use `str()`. Use `data` that I gave previous comment. You'll see, it works.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Alperen . how can i add a new line in last element of dict of for loop?

Comment: That works. i got exactly what i wanted. but to be honest i feel bad because i really don't understand your code line += key + "," line = line[:-1]+"\n" : Could you please explain what line[:-1] means. 
I think you have changed entities of my dict to list and you stored it every time in a line  . correct me please if iam wrong?
my question is: what does -1 means? you wrote als comment "delete last character" which characted will be deleted?
Thank you for your help and i will be happy if you could make me understand the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157401/discussion-between-alperen-and-ahmyohlin).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a row of the dictionary keys, then a row of the values.

```
for x in data:
    w.writerow(x.keys())
    w.writerow(x.values())
```

Comment: thank for answering. your tip works but i got all entities in one column. My goal, that next entity should be writen in the next column.
Name  
Alex  
Old
22
------------
Name  Old
Alex      22

my target is:
Name  Old      
Alex     22